# Custom Popup Window

Tags: javascript, html, css, object, popup

I have created a design for my web page.
The issue I face is I am unsure how to create a smaller window popup, with my design.

The window will open up once I click on an image and display it's image on it with it's specific information.

I am unsure if I need some kind of JavaScript object to save their information.

This is kind of where I have started but I am lost.
I need the image based on which is clicked.
So to display the object I need to display it based on which image I click and unsure how.

Below is my design.

```
function Cupcakes(type, name, description, Price, cost, image){
    this.type = type; //create an instant of object
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.Price = Price;
    this.cost = cost;
    thi.image = image;
    this.displayInfo = function(){
      var info ="<div class='divCell1' id = 'line1'>";
      info += this.name + "</div><div class='divCell2' id = 'line2'>";
      info += this.description + "</div><div class='divCell3' id = 'line3'>";
      info += this.Price + "<div>Price <br>";
      info += this.cost + "</div><div class = 'divCell4' id='line4'>";
      info += this.image + "</div>";
      return info;
    }   
}

// define an array to store products
var product_list = [];
var cart = [];
var cost = "Half Dozen: $7.00 <br> Dozen:  $12.50 <br> Party Size [20 cupcakes]:  $18.00"
var desc1 = ' Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus orci elit, lobortis nec neque in, condimentum gravida velit. Suspendisse maximus nisl et vehicula placerat. Sed elit turpis, venenatis sit amet tortor vel, interdum cursus mi.';  
var image = " ";
var product = new Products('cupcake','Winter Festival', desc1, 15.99);
product_list.push(product);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pop-ups are blocked on browsers by default. Use a div with `position:fixed` instead. You can hide/show it using `display:none` / `display:inline-block`

```js
function show(){
var stats =  document.getElementById("aa").style.display;
  
if (stats == "none"){  
document.getElementById("aa").style.display = "inline-block";
} else {
document.getElementById("aa").style.display = "none";  
}
}
```

```css
body {
height: 100%;
background: honeydew;
}

#aa {  
  font-weight: bold;
  position:fixed;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin: auto;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 15px;  
  background: gold;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  border: 4px dashed black;
}

button {
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: left;
  color: white;
  background: crimson; 
  padding: 15px;
}

#text {
  text-align: justify;
    -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 3;
}
```

```html
<div id=text><button onClick=show()>click</button> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nam nibh. Nunc varius facilisis eros. Sed erat. In in velit quis arcu ornare laoreet. Curabitur adipiscing luctus massa. Integer ut purus ac augue commodo commodo. Nunc nec mi eu justo tempor consectetuer. Etiam vitae nisl. In dignissim lacus ut ante. Cras elit lectus, bibendum a, adipiscing vitae, commodo et, dui. Ut tincidunt tortor. Donec nonummy, enim in lacinia pulvinar, velit tellus scelerisque augue, ac posuere libero urna eget neque. Cras ipsum. Vestibulum pretium, lectus nec venenatis volutpat, purus lectus ultrices risus, a condimentum risus mi et quam. Pellentesque auctor fringilla neque. Duis eu massa ut lorem iaculis vestibulum. Maecenas facilisis elit sed justo. Quisque volutpat malesuada velit.</div>
<div id=aa style="display:none">CONTENT</div>
```

Comment: yes this is very close to what I want! just out of curiosity, can the "click to close" be on the pop up?

Answer (score 1):

Pure CSS solution with undercover checkbox:

```css
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;  
  background: lavender;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}

input { 
  display: none;
}

#target { 
  display: none;
}

#click:checked ~ label > #target {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 80%;
  width: 80%;
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/bv80Nb7.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  outline: 6px double teal;
}

.item {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  cursor: pointer;  
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;  
}

#warning {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="click" name="click" value="click" />

<label for="click">
<p class="item"><b>CLICK HERE</b></p>
<div id=target class="item"><h1 id=warning>THE POP-UP CONTENT</h1></div>  
</label>
```

Comment: wow this is amazing! thank you for this example. It works like a charm as well. Surprised there is no JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

You question is very very confusing.

Basic javascript (considering jQuery) for you:

You can save the information of each cupcake on it element. Like this:

```
<div class="cupcake" data-price="Half Dozen: $7.00..." data-description="My description">
[...]
</div>

<div class="cupcake" data-price="Half Dozen: $12.00..." data-description="My description 2">
[...]
</div>
```

and in jquery:

```
$(".cupcake").on("click", function(){
    var price = $(this).data("price"); //Getting the price information
    var desc = $(this).data("price"); //Getting the description information
    //Here you can use all information, call functions and show your small popup
});
```

Based in what `div` you click, the variable `price` and `desc` will receive the correct information.

This is a little bit useful for you ?

If you want, please edit your question and try to be more specific, because I don't get your real problem. (Maybe it's my english)

Comment: the set up you have is definitely in the direction I want. However, when I test your example nothing happens when I click my image.

Comment: The bind is correct ?? For example, I setup a `.click` on `.cupcake` class, so if you click anywhere ate the div, the function click will be called.